# How do I inject a local file as an argument to a command to run inside a docker container?

Tags: bash, docker

Scenario:

I have a postgres container named `db` running on a machine. I am in a directory on the host and have an SQL script named `patch.sql`. I wish to apply this script to the database inside the container.

Were I to be inside the container and have the script also inside the container, I would run

```
psql -U user -d db -f patch.sql
```

Since I am outside the container, I could naively try

```
docker exec -i db psql -U user -d db -f patch.sql
```

but of course, this would look for a file named `patch.sql` inside the container, while it is actually on the host machine.

My current workaround is

```
cat patch.sql | docker exec -i db /bin/sh -c "cat $@ > patch.sql"
docker exec -i db psql -U user -d db -f patch.sql
docker exec -i db rm patch.sql
```

Is there away to elegantly reduce this to a one-liner?

I am aware, how to place the file inside the container, this is exactly what my workaround does. I am thinking of some trick with I/O redirection to place the file into the command.

I do not want to mount volumes and I cannot do this, since the container is already running anyway. The idea is to avoid moving the file into the container.

Comment: I would install `psql` on the host and just not use `docker exec` here.

Comment: @DavidMaze care to justify this? Just keep in mind that this should be applicable to a production environment that I'm in.

Comment: (a) The file you're running is already on the right partitioned filesystem; the `docker cp` gymnastics you're doing aren't necessary.  (b) `docker` anything effectively requires root privileges on the host and `docker exec` gets a root shell in the container; you can run `psql` as an unprivileged user.  (c) For that matter you can run `psql` from a remote host, but not `docker exec`.  (d) `psql` is the same way you'd deal with non-Docker local and cloud-hosted databases; you don't need a special setup just to deal with Docker here.

Comment: (b)+(c) - yes, that sounds like the way to go. The reason we're running docker here is a temporary step before moving into kubernetes, plus this server is housing three databases for three separate deployments. Docker lets me isolate them from each other and also run different versions of PG.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe could try directly pipe the `patch.sql` file content to psql, like

```sh
cat patch.sql | docker exec -i db psql -U user -d db -f -
```

or just

```sh
cat patch.sql | docker exec -i db psql -U user -d db
```

Comment: That's a non-answer, really, since my workaround is doing that anyway. I'm thinking of some smart shell redirection/piping/whatever to achieve this, but my knowledge of bash is limited.

Comment: Refer to the [doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#volume-shared-filesystems) of docker, you could use `-v` to identify local file/folder to the docker volume.

Comment: I'm sorry that I haven't made this obvious enough, but I do not want to mount volumes and I cannot do this, since the container is already running anyway. I shall edit my question accordingly.

Comment: So you don't want volume, and seems don't want the file left in the container? Just directly pipe it then

Comment: This appears to work. I was having trouble getting errors like "this is not a TTY" and being concerned that feeding a bunch of lines of script to a command is not quite the same as the psql utility processing the file internally. In order not to meddle with the production database, I was trying out also things like `cat file | docker exec -i container cat - > otherfile` and it wasn't working properly. I'm still not sure that I gained a general understanding, but +1 for solving my immediate problem.